# How do I scale down a model while having the Normals lines' default size be scaled down accordingly with them?

Tags: transforms, normals

[image: The Default one]

[image: The down scaled in size one]

Above is default.
Below is the one downscaled in size.

I've been having issues making the normal lines' default size retain their original default size upon rescaling models. This still affects it even after Applying all transforms to it.

I also have this issue when rescaling models/armatures as a whole in Blender, though it's mainly noticeable when it's rescaled to a significant degree (which I need to do in order to import into a certain other program I'm working with).

Edit: I should specify I'm seeking to make the normal lines size change be its default when exported to other programs, not just the ability to view it at the normal size but still retain the undesired size as its true default.

Comment: Don't know whether this will help, but In the viewport overlay dropdown you can check the 'Constant Screen Size Normals icon at the right-hand end of the Normals settings line. Let me know if you can't find it, or if you found it and it helped, and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Not able to find it within the dropdown. https://imgur.com/a/P3kDMlr
Using version 2.90.1 for reference (because of some add ons potentially not being compatible in newer versions)

Comment: Ah sorry. It looks as if it was added in version 3.0. It's not in LTS version 2.93 either. :^(

Comment: I could try out the latest version and see what results it gives there at a later time I reckon. Though there should still be a method fix for older versions I reckon right? Dunno how else models I've downloaded online would not have the same issue I have when scaling models in general (in older versions too).

Comment: To be honest I very rarely have normal display turneed on. I use the Face orientation overlay far more often to check the normal direction and have that quickly available via the quick menu.